# foreach в обратном направлении

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Можно ли считать информацию с массива, начиная с последнего элемента массива?Количество данных в массиве неизвестно. Нужно сделать именно циклом foreach.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Можно попробовать так:

```
foreach(array_reverse($arr) as $element) {
    // code
}
```

Функция [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ :) очень помогли :)

Comment: @Аноним Если ответ правильный или помогло, отметите как лучшый ответ. Галочку поставьте